# How to handle requirements based resource authorization when there are many resource permissions with respect to performance?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I've got a web service which makes use of JWT based authentication. In some samples i have seen that permissions are added to the claims identity and then queried in the `AuthorizationHandler`.

Is this the way to go for production level solutions too? Since the permissions are encoded in the JWT token i am concerned with the performance implications of having a very big JWT token.

Given that at some point you could end up with a JWT token of 1mb+ and above, this may lead to very bad performance if the web api client has insufficient upload speed.

Are there best practices to deal with a large amount of permissions? (Currently i am thinking that the way to go probably would be doing cached db queries to access permission grants)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed, shoving too many claims into a JWT brings problems with it. Some servers will stop parsing the headers if they exceed a certain size. In our tests, IIS stopped accepting requests after ~150 scope claims (~2KB of JWT), so you don't have a lot of room to play with.

You should limit the usage of JWT to authentication. If the application has access to authorization data, you can use the token to fetch the permission claims for that user from the database or some authorization/policy service.

ASP.NET Core provides an interface for these kinds of scenarios. If you implement an [`IClaimsTransformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and register it, ASP.NET Core [will call it when it authenticates the user](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Http/Authentication.Core/src/AuthenticationService.cs#L85-L98). Then you'll have a chance to populate the `ClaimsPrincipal` with the authorization claims for the user.

One thing you need to look out for is that it is called every time an authentication occurs, so you need to check if you've already populated the claims to prevent duplicating claims. If you do it right, you'll need to perform a single query for every request to fetch the authorization claims for the user.

A sample implementation:

```cs
public class LoadUserClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private AppDbContext _db;

    public LoadUserClaimsTransformer(AppDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        // check if we've already populated the claims
        if (principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "permission"))
        {
            return principal;
        }

        if (principal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
        {
            var userId = principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            var permissions = await _db.Set<Permission>().Where(it => it.UserId == userId).ToListAsync();
            foreach (var permission in permissions)
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("permission", permission.Key));
            }
        }

        return principal;
    }
}
```

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, LoadUserClaimsTransformer>();
    // ...
}
```

Once the claims are added to `ClaimsPrincipal`, you can use `[Authorize]` annotations for declarative checks, or `IAuthorizationService` for imperative ones, or for resource-based authorizations.

### Resources:

- https://sdoxsee.github.io/blog/2020/01/06/stop-overloading-jwts-with-permission-claims
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-5.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation?view=aspnetcore-5.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0